# primary and secondary intemediate certificate Configuration in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, jboss

We are using Apache 2.2.27 and windows 2008 Standard server.  It is a production web server.  We had configured ssl earlier but now we have to renew the certificates.  We got three certificates maincert.crt, primarycertificate.crt and secondarycertificate.crt.  In Configuration i have copied primary and secondary certificate to another file and renamed the certificate(Copied both the files up to Beginning and Ending Tags).  But i am not able to start the apache server.  Please help me to resolve the Issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

please check your error log and paste it here (for example at /var/log/apache2/error.log)

there are many possible reasons for the failure:

- maybe your private key isnt matching your certificate
- wrong file permissions for the .crts
- there is any other misconfiguration
- etc etc

Comment: Hi Kevin Thanks for your quick reply.  The issue was public and private certificates were not mathching which i got to know from below website. https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html.  We Renewed the certificates. Now ssl is working Fine.